# Converting specific values from a dictionary to float

Tags: python-3.x

I have this dictionary

```
    dict_X = {
            'A': {'a': 371, 'b': 4925, 'c': 39, 'd': 8},
            'B': {'a': 400, 'b': 4659, 'c': 37, 'd': 11},
            'C': {'a': 19, 'b': 214, 'c': 1, 'd': 1},
            'D': {'a': 16, 'b': 115, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}
        }
```

I need to convert the values of 'c' and 'd' to float and find ratio of 'c' to 'd'.

I know that I have to use float() method, what I cannot figure out is how to use that for the values in a dictionary within a dictionary.

Need to convert the values to 'c' and 'd' to float to find the ratio of 'c':'d'. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you want to update all the `c` and `d` keys inside the `dict_X` object to become float? Or do you just need them to be made into floats before your calculations

Comment: look up how to access a dictionary value using a key, and you should be good

Comment: I tried "float_qb_stats = {outer_k : {float(inner_v) for (inner_k , inner_v) in outer_v.items()} for (outer_k , outer_v) in quarterback_stats.items()}". @TheGamer007, I need to convert the values to float before calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted in the comments is almost correct, except you forgot to retain the keys for the inner dict, making the nested structures `set`s instead. The correct dict comprehension would be:

```
{outer_k: {inner_k: float(inner_v) for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items()} for outer_k, outer_v in dict_X.items()}
```

However, this converts all the values (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`) into floats instead of just `c` and `d`. You can limit it to only those keys using the following `if-else` condition:

```
{outer_k: {inner_k: float(inner_v) if inner_k in ['c','d'] else inner_v for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items()} for outer_k, outer_v in dict_X.items()}
```

Or, since according to what you said you only need the float conversion for a calculation, just cast it before using it in that expression and leave `dict_X` as it is. For example,

```
float_ratio = float(dict_X['A']['c'])/dict_X['A']['d']
```

Converting just one of them is enough to make the result a `float`.

Comment: Thank you TheGamer007, I figured the solution right after my last reply. It was a couple of lines long, but it was close to the third solution you gave. Cheers mate!